# onchange event in JavaScript - dependent option list

Tags: javascript, html, vba, internet-explorer, dom-events

I am trying to automate some task in IE with information from an Excel file. My knowledge in VBA lets me get to a point where I answer to a question in the website with "yes" and that should open another question with more options to select.
As said I get to the first yes but then the other question doesn't appear.

Here is part of the JavaScript code from the website and part of the HTML code:

```
    var elemData = jQuery.data( elem );

    // If no elemData is found then we must be trying to bind to one of the
    // banned noData elements
    if ( !elemData ) {
        return;
    }

    var events = elemData.events = elemData.events || {},
        eventHandle = elemData.handle, eventHandle;

    if ( !eventHandle ) {
        elemData.handle = eventHandle = function() {
            // Handle the second event of a trigger and when
            // an event is called after a page has unloaded
            return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && !jQuery.event.triggered ?
                jQuery.event.handle.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
                undefined;
        };
```

```html
<p>
 <span class="i_lbReq">First question</span> //this line has the 'change: eventHandle' event/function associated to it
    <br></br>
 <select name="meetingQuestionAnswer(220674)" class="auto-save">
    <option value=""> --- --- </option>
    <option value="Yes" selected="">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
    </select>
 </p>
<div class="recursive-question" id="meetingDependentQuestion(220674)"> //this line has the 'change: eventHandle' event/function associated to it
<div id="meetingQuestionAnswerDiv(221010)">
     <input name="meetingQuestionValidatorRule(221010)" type="hidden" value="">
      <input name="meetingQuestionReadOnly(221010)" type="hidden" value="">
      <p>
 <span class="i_lb">Dependent question 1</span>
        <br></br>
        <select name="meetingQuestionAnswer(221010)" class="auto-save">
        <option value="" selected=""> --- --- </option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
      </p>
 <div class="recursive-question" id="meetingDependentQuestion(221010)">
        <div id="meetingQuestionAnswerDiv(221011)">
       <input name="meetingQuestionValidatorRule(221011)" type="hidden" value="">
          <input name="meetingQuestionReadOnly(221011)" type="hidden" value="">
          <p>
            <span class="i_lb">Dependent question 2</span>
            <br></br>
            <select name="meetingQuestionAnswer(221011)" class="auto-save">
            <option value="" selected=""> --- --- </option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
          </p>
   <div class="recursive-question" id="meetingDependentQuestion(221011)">
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I have tried with VBA to use the method .FireEvent "onchange" on the first question element but it didn't work

```html
Dim ieApp As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set ieApp = IEWindowFromTitle("Profile Form Detail View")
If Not ieApp Is Nothing Then
    Set ieDoc = ieApp.document
End If


For Each cell In GMF.Sheets("BUDGET").Range("B4:B" & Cells(Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
    If cell.Value = "MRR" Then
        ieDoc.getElementsByName("meetingQuestionAnswer(220674)")(0).Value = "Yes" 'this works fine
        ieDoc.getElementsByName("meetingQuestionAnswer(220674)")(0).FireEvent "onchange" 
        ieDoc.getElementsByName("meetingQuestionAnswerDiv(221010)")(0).Value = "Yes" 'this one never appears after saying yes in the previous question
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: @QHarr I added it in the question

Comment: Is this a public or private url please? And should your referenced element change during the loop as currently only 2 elements are referenced even if more than once cell contains MRR?

Comment: Unfortunately is private.. but I can show more of the code if needed

Comment: Just trying to visualize as your first element looks like a dropdown not an input element. So, I would have expected something like ieDoc.querySelector("select[name='meetingQuestionAnswer(220674)']'").click : ieDoc.querySelector("[name='meetingQuestionAnswer(220674)'] [value=Yes]").Selected = True

Comment: I'm getting an error in method 'querySelector' from the object 'JScriptTypeInfo'

Comment: It means it doesn’t like that syntax. I’ll have a look in a minute.

Comment: Thanks! The second line is working ok though. It changes the Yes/No value

Comment: Is there another action that needs to happen? I have posted that answer below for the second part.

Comment: No.. it just saying yes to a first question so then the second one appears. If you say No then nothing happens

Comment: And by saying yes to first is when second should appear?

Comment: Exactly! If i see what's related to the first question regarding the code there's an event 'change' associated to the element and the funtion eventHandle (posted in JavaScript code) to the event

Comment: I don't see a change event in the js. However, you can then use .FireEvent "onchange" on the appropriate element to attempt to fire. Have you used this on the right element?

Comment: That's the first thing I tried but didn't work either.

Comment: I would suggest trying selenium basic then if you are allowed to install.

Answer (score 1):

Try to refer code example below may help to solve your issue.

```
Dim event_onChange As Object 
Set event_onChange = hdoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents") 
event_onChange.initEvent "change", True, False 

vSelect.dispatchEvent event_onChange
```

Reference:

[Vba, HTMLSelect: FireEvent OnChange or DispatchEvent](https://codedocu.com/Office-365/Access/Controls/web-Browser/Vba,-HTMLSelect_colon_-FireEvent-OnChange-or-DispatchEvent?1890)

Comment: THANKS!!!! Worked perfectly! And thanks for the reference.. in my mind I knew I neede to do this but didn't know how.

Comment: I'm having some problems with this again but I'll edit the code because I saw something it might help

Comment: You need to inform us with the detailed example and steps, like where you have the issue and what did you tried till now. It can help us to understand the issue in better way.