# HTML events load slower than macro runs

Tags: javascript, html, vba, events

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
      var questionType = 'RQ_CHOICE';
      var elementName="meetingQuestionAnswer(220674)";
      if(questionType=="RQ_CHOICE" || questionType=="RQ_YES_NO" ){
       $("select[name='" + elementName + "']").bind("change",function(event){
        loadDependentQuestion("220674",'select');
       });
      }
      if(questionType=="RQ_CHOICE_BULLET" || questionType=="RQ_RATING_SCALE"){
       $("input:radio[name='" + elementName + "']").bind("change",function(event){
        loadDependentQuestion("220674",'radio');
       });
      }
      bindDelegateToloadDependentQuestion("220674");
 </script>
```

With help I have solved to get a dependent dropboz to trigger from the answer of previous question with the event "onchange" from JavaScript (see link for question about this) but now the JavaScript code seems to run slower than the macro does so when I need to answer the next question with data from Excel, the macros stops with an error saying the object doesn't exist (because the new dropdown (my object) didn't appear yet). If I debug and then I manually go line by line then it gives time to JavaScript to load the new dropdown and everything works great.

[onchange event in JavaScript - dependent option list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109888/onchange-event-in-javascript-dependent-option-list/54123676#54123676)

I have tried using wait function from VBA after triggering the event and also the loop with do events but still it doesn't work.

I have also made a do loop to repeat the action while the object is nothing but didn't work either.

This is the script associated to the three questions:

```html
   
    'First question
    ieDoc.getElementsByName("question1")(0).Value = "Yes"
    event_onChange.initEvent "change", True, False
    ieDoc.getElementsByName("question1")(0).dispatchEvent event_onChange
    While ieApp.Busy Or ieApp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
    application.wait "00:00:02"
    
    'Second question - the one that is not loading
    Do while ieDoc.getElementsByName("question2")(0) Is Nothing Then
        For i = 1 To totalRng.Cells.count
            If totalRng.Cells(i).Offset(, savingsRng.Column - Cells(i).Column) > 0 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                While ieApp.Busy Or ieApp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
                ieDoc.getElementsByName("question2")(0).Value = "Yes"
                Exit For
            Else
                While ieApp.Busy Or ieApp.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
                ieDoc.getElementsByName("question2")(0).Value = "No"
            End If
        Next i
     Loop
```

Comment: You could add a `do...until` until `ieDoc.getElementsByName("question2") is not nothing` ?

Comment: what is the html for dropdown that appears?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want a loop until present and make it based on time out to avoid potential infinite loop.

```
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
Dim t As Date, ele As Object
t = Timer
Do
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ele = ieDoc.querySelector("[name='meetingQuestionAnswer(221010)']")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
Loop While ieDoc.querySelectorAll("[name='meetingQuestionAnswer(221010)']").Length = 0
If Not ele Is Nothing Then
    'do something
End If
```

Comment: The object i present if the event is triggered. This happens when you choose an answer from the previous dropdown list. I will try this you are saying

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.. the weird thing is as soon I stop/pause the macro the question shows up (so the code works I guess)

Comment: Before that dropdown appears if you check the browser does an element with name question2 already exist?  Also, what does _doesn't work_ mean?

Comment: No! It doesn't exist. It's not written in the code until you choose Yes in the previous question. I mean that loop keeps going and going until I force it to stop

Comment: That implies the wrong selector. Can you share the html for the element you expect to see appear please?

Comment: The code is here in other question... I don't know if I should close this one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109888/onchange-event-in-javascript-dependent-option-list/54123676#54123676

Comment: Is it the one with id as follows?  id="meetingDependentQuestion(221010)"

Comment: No... The objects I assign values to are the ones like  name="meetingQuestion(#####)"

Comment: So, is the element you are waiting for: name="meetingQuestionAnswer(221010)"  ?

Comment: Yes, that one and If I say 'Yes' to that one too the question '221011' (same  name different number) should appear as well but it doesn't

Comment: Then the element to look for should have a selector similar to my edited answer.

Comment: I added the script if you want to see it

Comment: What happens with my edited answer? Also, if you use #meetingDependentQuestion(221010)  instead of [name='meetingQuestionAnswer(221010)']